# NullReferenceException After Migrating ASP.NET C# Website from IIS 6.0 to IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, iis

I am new to .NET Platform, I am from J2EE background.I don't have problem in reading the code. However i am not quite familiar with the Runtime environment

**Task provided to me:**

I need to migrate an ASP.NET C# website from IIS 6.0 to IIS 8.5.

**My Actions so far:**

1. Published the website using Visual studio 2010
2. The website uses Oracle database hence i have installed Oracle client and configured the database in tnsnames.ora
3. Added the published website to the IIS 8.5 server using "add website" option and started the website

**Environment details:**

1. TO-BE Runtime: IIS 8.5 , Microsoft Windows Server 2012R2
2. AS-IS Runtime : IIS 6.0 , Oracle database is being used by the website.

**Problem:**
The default webpage is getting loaded, however when i click a button, i noticed the following exception in windows events

```
    Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://172.21.126.88:28080/Profile.aspx 
    Request path: /Profile.aspx 
    User host address: 10.30.54.97 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 14 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Code_Profile.btnGetCustDet_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Exception related code**

**ASP.net page with Button click action**

```
  <td>
<asp:Button ID="btnGetCustDet" runat="server" OnClick="btnGetCustDet_Click" Text="Get Details" Width="111px" />
</td>
```

**C# function handling that event.**

```
protected void btnGetCustDet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxCustNameE.Text = "Button click entry";
```

Couldn't locate exactly where this exception is getting triggered. as per exception trace, at Code_Profile.**btnGetCustDet_Click**(Object sender, EventArgs e) But even the first line of **btnGetCustDet_Click** is not getting executed. So i am stuck here

Please advise , i suspect some migration issue. Please let me know if there is any standard procedure to perform and validate this migration

Comment: can you please answer your application build on which .NET version and your IIS your application run under which .NET version?

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper : As per web.config file, its **3.5.0**. In the current IIS 6.0 the website is ASP.NET is configured as **2.0.5**

Comment: make both in sync and it will start working. try changing target framework in IIS and let me know the  result